# Archivo Styles.xml de android studio

Tags: android

En el editor de android studio , dentro de la carpeta values  solo me aparece 2 archivos, "colors y string" mas no el archivo Style. ¿que puedo hacer para q aparezca ese archivo?'

Comment: Creo que a tu pregunta le falta algo mas de desarrollo consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Bienvenido, por favor edita tu pregunta agregando más información, revisa [ask] saludos.

Answer (score -1):

Si has creado bien el proyecto bien el proyecto, una vez se indexe bien, deberías tener algo así:

[image: Values]

Si no es así, puedes crear tu mismo los archivos ".xml" de la siguiente manera:

[image: Crear archivo]

[image: Style.xml]